# subdir-objects option for automake doesn't work

Tags: c, makefile, autotools

After reading the [autotools mythbuster](https://autotools.io), I have tried to write a little example of the non recursive makefile with the use of *subdir-objects* in order to have my binary in the directory of my source files.

Here is the the **organization** of my little test:

```
/
   autogen.sh
   configure.ac
   Makefile.am
   src/
      main.c
```

The **autogen.sh** :

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Running aclocal..." ; aclocal $ACLOCAL_FLAGS || exit 1
echo "Running autoheader..." ; autoheader || exit 1
echo "Running autoconf..." ; autoconf || exit 1
echo "Running automake..." ; automake --add-missing --copy --gnu || exit 1
./configure "$@"
```

The **configure.ac** :

```
AC_PREREQ([2.69])
AC_INIT([test], [0.0.1], [devel@hell.org])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([src/main.c])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])

# Checks for programs.
AC_PROG_CC
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([1.14 foreign subdir-objects])
AM_MAINTAINER_MODE([enable])
AC_OUTPUT(Makefile)
```

The **Makefile.am** :

```
MAINTAINERCLEANFILES = Makefile.in aclocal.m4 config.h.in configure depcomp install-sh missing compile
bin_PROGRAMS=toto
toto_SOURCES=src/main.c
```

I compile everything with :

```
./autogen.sh
make
```

I thought that the binary toto would have been created in the src directory with the option *subdir-objects* but it seems that this option have no effect and the toto binary is always generated in the root directory.

I have also tried to pass this option in the Makefile.am with AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = subdir-objects but wihtout success.

Comment: make will automatically look for a file named Makefile or makefile or Makefile.mak or makefile.mak.  It will not look for a file name Makefile.am.  so use make -f Makefile.am

Comment: `make -f Makefile.am` will _not_ work. The `Makefile` is generated from the `Makefile.am` by Automake and `configure`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not what the subdir-objects option does.  It puts *intermediate* build results, especially `*.o` *object files*, in the same directory as the sources from which they are built.  In particular, you should find `main.o` there instead of in the top directory.

The final build result, on the other hand, must be what and where you specify in your Automake file.  If you want `toto` to go in the `src/` directory too, then use this `Makefile.am`:

```
MAINTAINERCLEANFILES = Makefile.in aclocal.m4 config.h.in configure depcomp install-sh missing compile
bin_PROGRAMS=src/toto
src_toto_SOURCES=src/main.c
```

Comment: I can attest from experience that you totally can use Automake this way for non-recursive builds.  However, you may find it useful to use limited recursion for documentation or header file *installs*.

Comment: Also, I never have found an `autogen.sh` needful, and everything listed in your `MAINTAINERCLEANFILES` variable either is cleaned by default by `make maintainer-clean` or else probably shouldn't be cleaned at all.  Myself, I'd get rid of both of those.

Comment: I have taken the autogen.sh and the MAINTAINERCLEANFILES's trick from the examples of code of the [elementary](http://docs.enlightenment.org/auto/elementary/group__Start.html) library (EFL, Enligthenment).